# Can this code be made more generic?

Tags: asp.net, generics

I'm creating website functionality in c#/Asp.Net 4.0.

I have a function that queries my database and returns a list of loan providers ("lenders").

Once I have built my list, I then iterate through the list and perform an HttpPost for each of them. Each lender has very specific and unique data requirements, so I have a class for each lender, that inherits an interface.

```
MrLenderRequest : IPingtreeRequest
```

When I loop through the list, I need to map the data to the class. Currently I do it in this very ungeneric way, calling this code from within the loop:

```
    IPingtreeRequest GetLenderRequest(string lender)
    {
        IPingtreeRequest lenderRequest = null;

        switch (lender)
        {
            case "MrLender":
                lenderRequest = new MrLenderRequest(_data);
                break;
            default:
                lender.ThrowCaseNotHandled();
                break;
        }

        return lenderRequest;
    }
```

This is ok, when you have 4 or 5, but not if there are 50 or more. I wondered if there was a more elegant/generic way of mapping the class.

Comment: I suppose you could use reflection to get the class name and match it to the string.  You could even cache the results in a dictionary for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Type.GetType` and then use `Activator` to instantiate the object.

```
string lender = "MrLender";
var lenderType = Type.GetType(lender + "Request"); // Include your namespaces
IPingtreeRequest lenderRequest = (IPingtreeRequest)Activator.CreateInstance(lenderType);
```

Comment: Lol, that was super quick 15 seconds after my comment

Comment: Currently, the constructor is injected with the variable _data - is this possible using this method?

Comment: Yes there is an overload that accepts parameters as an array.